Any way to to get event grid topic secret dynamically with Azure CLI?
Is there any way to get Azure Event Grid Topic secret dynamically in using Azure CLI?


I have one Azure Event Grid Topic named demoevent with below Access keys:

To get these Azure Event Grid Topic secrets dynamically using Azure CLI, you can make use of below command:
az eventgrid topic key list --resource-group <resourceGroupName> --name <topicName>

Response:

To get the value of specific key, you can use below CLI command by adding --query in it at the end:
az eventgrid topic key list --output tsv --resource-group <resourceGroupName> --name <topicName> --query "key1"

Response:

